# How can I make golint run on VS Code on type instead of on save?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code and the Go extension from lukehoban:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go

It seems like the golint is run when you save the file, is there a way for me to make golint run when I start typing? Usually linting happens when we type on other extensions and languages such as jslint, and tslint on VS Code. It would be nice to have the option to also be able to do this with golint.

What could I do to achieve this?

Comment: If the file isn't saved, how is go lint supposed to run against it?

Comment: Configure your editor to save on all keystrokes?

Comment: @DmitryGashko: I have no idea if, or how, other languages do it. But the Go tool chain works on files on disk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like it's not possible at all.

The only available configs regarding golint are:

```
  // Run Lint tool on save.
  "go.lintOnSave": true,

  // Specifies Lint tool name.
  "go.lintTool": "golint",

  // Flags to pass to Lint tool (e.g. ["-min_confidence=.8"])
  "go.lintFlags": [],
```

Maybe you can hack this by changing these options though:

```
  // Controls auto save of dirty files. Accepted values:  "off", "afterDelay", "onFocusChange" (editor loses focus), "onWindowChange" (window loses focus). If set to "afterDelay", you can configure the delay in "files.autoSaveDelay".
  "files.autoSave": "off",

  // Controls the delay in ms after which a dirty file is saved automatically. Only applies when "files.autoSave" is set to "afterDelay"
  "files.autoSaveDelay": 1000,
```

You could set `files.autoSave` to `afterDelay` and a lower `files.autoSaveDelay`.

Comment: I believe the lintOnSave config now only accepts a string of either: "file", "workspace", "package", or "off".

Answer (score 5):

This side of Go makes me crazy...

So, I've found an option called "go.useLanguageServer" (most likely I had found it some-when earlier, but for some reason it's not so easy to find that option anyway).

```json
"go.useLanguageServer": true,
```

Also, there're these options:

```json
"go.languageServerExperimentalFeatures": {
    "diagnostics": true,
    "documentLink": true
},
"go.liveErrors": {
    "enabled": true,
    "delay": 500,
},
```

Comment: Seems to work great out of the box. This should be the accepted answer.